# Does ImmutableList have AsReadOnly like method?

Tags: c#, immutable-collections

AsReadOnly() is a convenient method to get a read-only image (not expensive compared to immutable collections' copies) of a collection. I am wondering if ImmutableList has AsReadOnly like method? If no, any easy way to implement similarly?

Comment: What does the word Immutable mean to you?

Comment: An immutable list is already read only, why would you want a method like this?

Comment: @DavidG I think the read-only image might have a better performance. Foe ImmutableList, every time I access it, I get an expensive copy. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You only get a copy if you modify it.

Comment: @user1899020 no, accessing an element does not copy immutable collection. If you modify it, a new instance will be created (but some immutable data structure share "common" data hence memory overhead is often not as big as many people expect)

Comment: Honestly you could have tried this yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImmutableList<T>` is copied by reference so is perfectly safe to pass around without a performance penalty. Thus there is no need for an `AsReadOnly` method as it wouldn't make it any easier to copy.

Comment: If I put an immutable list as a public auto-implemented property. When I use getter to access it. Does it make an expensive copy or just reference?

Comment: That is a reference - it works like every other reference type.

Answer (score 3):

Immutable collections are inherently read-only. You can easily check in the documentation that [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.111).aspx) already implements `IReadOnlyList<T>` and `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` interfaces.

Memory is not allocated when you access elements from immutable collection. On the other hand, when you add an element to some immutable data structure, a new immutable collection is created (and some memory is used). Many immutable collections' implementations do not copy all the data to a new collection but instead share some data from with the old one, so in most cases you should not be too concerned with memory usage/allocation time.

Some collections, e.g. [`ImmutableHashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467173(v=vs.111).aspx), have a documentation which states that they are optimized in terms of number of memory allocations.

The idea behind sharing some data between immutable collection is not complicated. Wikipedia has an simple example [(with a nice diagram)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Purely_functional_list_after.svg) showing how memory can be saved in case of immutable singly-linked lists.